# Word Occurrences count in PHP - scaling and optimization

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, regex

You have a large collection of very short (<100 characters) to medium-long (~5k characters) text items in a Mysql table. You want a solid and fast algorithm to obtain an aggregated word occurrency count in all the items.

Items selected can be as few as one (or none) and as many as 1M+, so the size of the text that has to be analyzed can vary wildly.

The current solution involves:

- reading text from the selected records into a text variable
- preg_replacing out everything that is not a "word" getting a somewhat cleaned up, shorter text (hashtags, @mentions, http(s):// links, numeric sequences such as phone numbers, etc. are not "words" and are parsed out)
- exploding what's left into a "buffer" array
- taking out everything that's shorter than two words and dumping everything else in a "master" array

the resulting array is then transformed with array_count_values, sorted (arsort), spliced a first time to have a more manageable array size, then parsed against stopwords lists in several languages, processed and spliced some more and finally output in JSON form as the list of the 50 most frequent words.

By tracing timing on the various steps of the operation sequence, the apparent bottleneck is in the query at first but as the item count increases, it rapidly moves to the **array_count_values** function (everything after that is more or less immediate).

On a ~ 10k items test run the total time for execution is ~3s from beginning to end; with 20k items it takes ~7s.

A (rather extreme but not impossible) case with 1.3M items takes 1m for the mysql query, and is able to parse roughly ~75k items per minute (so 17 minutes-ish is the estimate).

The result should be visualized as a result of an AJAX call, so with this kind of timing the UX is evidently disrupted. I'm looking for ways  to optimize everything as much as possible. A 30s load time may be  acceptable (however little realistic), 10 minutes (or more) is not.

I've tried batch processing by *array_count_values*-ing the chunks and then adding the resulting count arrays to a master array by key, but that helps only so much - the sum of the parts is equal (or slightly larger) than the total in terms of timing.

- I only need the 50 most frequent occurrences at the top of the list, so there's possibly some room for improvement by cutting a few corners.

Comment: That's a lot of words, which can help, but a small amount of code for context is usually way more valuable.

Comment: You are going the wrong way. Instead of trying to read all your database, to check to replace, to sort, etc. at each ajax requests, build a table of words with a count column once and for all, and update it at each insertion or deletion (with a trigger). Then you obtain the result with a simple query with a LIMIT and an ORDER BY clause. (clearly less than 1 sec)

Comment: @tadman I agree in general, but code is not the scope here. Finding a different perspective to a problem is. Code follows.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that is the kind of 'different perspective' I'm referring to in the comment immediately above. I thought of something similar but the content from which to derive the counted occurrences list can vary with each query performed - so it's not just "count the words in column so-so in that table" - the records may have to match a number of parameters to be included in the count.

Comment: @qqg: if I understand well the only thing that is varying is *in fine* the records selection, true?

Comment: On the other hand, there might be an index in a separate table with a pre-computed word count array associated to each item... I'll explore that. Most of the work would then lie in storing/retrieving the data (serialize? JSON encoded and stored as text?)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes, as it is now you select the records and then it counts.

Comment: Instead of building a primitive search engine why not leverage one of the existing ones like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) or [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co) which can probably get you 90% of the way there with almost no effort? The remaining 10% is learning how to use their toolset effectively. In any case, the brute-force approach is *put it all in memory* and just have at it with various matching algorithms. Persist in the database, but work in memory.

Comment: @qqg: a precomputed array isn't how I will describe it, but it's more or less the idea. You need three tables: 1.  text (text_id, text_content), 2. word (word_id, word_word), 3. text_word(fk_text_id, fk_word_id, count) (where fk_ columns are foreign keys from the table 1 and 2).

Comment: @tadman I looked into those and -as much as a solution of that kind will eventually need to be integrated in a relatively short term - and both appear to be probably a good fit for the problem (as everything scales up, fulltext -boolean- searches in mysql are also starting to wear thin quickly) it appears from the docs that something like word (occurrences) counting is too low-level for either solutions. It can probably be done but it's not immediate.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte attempting the index technique above on a sample of 10k contents, results in roughly 115k individual "words", from Aachen to Zytek, instantiated ~1.4M times; as this scales up, while I think the "words" table will hit more or less a plateau, the "text_word" table will grow linearly - so this gets quickly impractical, I fear.

Comment: @qqg: how many text entries max do you expect? Also how much place do you have for your database?

Answer (score 0):

1. dump the column(s) into a text file.  Suggest `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'x.txt'...`
2. (if on linux etc):  `tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' <x.txt | sort | uniq -c`

To get the top 50:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' <x.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nbr | head -50
```

If you need to tweak the definition of "word", such as dealing with punctuation, see the documentation on `tr`.  You may have trouble with contractions versus phrases in single-quotes.

Some of the cleansing of the text can (and should) be done in SQL:

```
WHERE col NOT LIKE 'http%'
```

Some can (and should) be done in the shell script.

For example, this will get rid of @variables and phone numbers and 0-, 1-, and 2-character "words":

```
egrep -v '^@|^([-0-9]+$|$|.$|..)$'
```

That can be in the pipe stream just before the first `sort`.

The only limitation is disk space.  Each step in the script is quite fast.

Test case:

The table:  176K rows of mostly text (including some linefeeds)

```
$ wc x3.txt
  3,428,398 lines  31,925,449 'words'  225,339,960 bytes

$ time tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' <x.txt | egrep -v '^@|^([-0-9]+$|$|.$|..)$' |
              sort | uniq -c | sort -nbr | head -50
 658569 the
 306135 and
 194778 live
 175529 rel="nofollow"
 161684 you
 156377 for
 126378 that
 121560 this
 119729 with
...
real    2m16.926s
user    2m23.888s
sys 0m1.380s
```

Fast enough?

I was watching it via `top`.  It seems that the slowest part is the first `sort`.  The `SELECT` took under 2 seconds (however, the table was probably cached in RAM).

Comment: I like this. My only qualms may lie in the fact that all this happens in a API so it'd be a few more *shell_exec*s than I'm comfortable with - but I have control on people using it (it's a non public platform) so that might be acceptable in terms of security.

Comment: @qqg - That's a one-line script (with a lot of piping).  That is, only one shell-exec.  Or am I not understanding your problem?